# How to create a custom activity from NativeActivity and how to run it?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am new to Workflows ,can any one suggest me good tutorials for Workflow foundation(with samples if possible).I have basic question on workflows  how to create a custom activity using NativeActivity so that i can pass two input for it .

Comment: [Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) Samples for .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459)

Comment: thank you it is really helpfull